# How to insert multiple default values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine you have a table  which all of its columns were created with the DEFAULT clause included, for example

```
BOX
----------
height
width
depth
```

currently I'd make the following query to use default values:

```
INSERT INTO BOX VALUES(DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT);
```

is there any other way to do this in Oracle? Preferably to indicate  insert clause to use all default values but without specifying it for every column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `DEFAULT` for one column and omit other columns.

```
INSERT INTO box (height) VALUES (DEFAULT);
```

As a result you'll get all columns with default values.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c2eb/1)** demo